# center only item in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I center .search as the only item in a .flex container?

```css
body{
    background-color:green;
}

.bar{
    background-color:yellow;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.search{
    background-color:red;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
            <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It works when I add more items:

```css
body {
    background-color:green;
}
.bar {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.search {
    background-color:red;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="menu"><a href="#">menu</a>

        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
            <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div class="closebar"><a href="#">close</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But why does it work when there are other items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you specify the `auto` value for left and right margin to `.search` element:

```css
body {
    background-color:green;
}
.bar {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.search {
    background-color:red;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bar">

        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
            <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you know the underlying reason?

Comment: nevermind, looked into "margin: 0 auto" a bit and I think I get it. The browser maxes out the margins, right?

Answer (score 1):

Set `justify-content: center;` instead of `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
body{
    background-color:green;
}

.bar{
    background-color:yellow;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.search{
    background-color:red;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
            <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**For More Info:**

> [Mozilla MDN - justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but I prefer the other solution. Upvoted.